# How to create context menu with the same choices as Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I apologize if this has already been answered.  I've looked and looked, and I can't find anything like what I want, which I find greatly surprising.  Please feel free to give me a "This has already been asked" with a link... :(

I'm in the early stages of creating a program in C#.  The main window will have a list of files which are relevant to my application.  I currently have them in a list view, although I can switch widget types if necessary.  What I'd like is to make it possible for a user to right-click on one or more of the file names which would bring up the same context menu as one would get in Explorer.  With e.g. "Open", "Edit", "Print", and etcetera.

Obviously I could put stuff in a context menu manually, but I'd like it to have the same choices as one would have in Explorer.  There will be Word documents and text files and various other odds and ends.  I don't know how the list of actions in the standard Windows context menu is populated, especially considering that the list changes depending on the file type selected and whether more than one file is selected.

I can provide code if necessary, although I don't have anything interesting yet.

So my questions are - How do I get the list of actions one gets when right-clicking a file or group of files in Explorer?  Is there a Windows API that I can call?  Or do I aggregate choices that I read in the registry?  And if so, what do I read?  Or what?

As a bonus, I'd like to be able to add a few commands of my own to the menu *only within my own application*.  Mostly all I can find is how to write an extension to the context menu such that I can add an action that appears always when clicking a specific file type.  That is NOT what I want.  This is a bonus though, and I can always add buttons or a drop down menu or something if this won't work or if it requires heroic coding.

Comment: Look in registry hive HKCR: It contains extension to file type to class ID to CLSID to "verb" (HKCR\CLSID\xxxxx\Verb) mapping... Someone may post proper APIs to read all of it.

Comment: That helps.  It would be nice to see if there's an API, but I could always scour the registry and build up a list of verbs.  Thanks!!

Comment: when you figure it out be sure to post your solution here as a answer to your own question to help the next guy who has the same problem.

Comment: I definitely will, although I'm hoping someone else has an answer...

Comment: Groveling the registry key will not show you dynamic verbs. You need to host the context menu object.

Comment: Because you're creating your own, am I correct in assuming that the `BrowserFolderDialog` and `OpenFileDialog` classes don't meet your needs?

Comment: @neontapir: No not really.  I don't want to open files or browse for files, I want a user to be able to treat files which I already know about in a fashion similar to Explorer.  These are files related to my task.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I want to add a thank you to @svic for removing the "C# -" part of the question title.  I thought that marking this as C# specific would make it easier for others to help.  I see now that this is actually better without the excess baggage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found this article which describes the process for c++ but I think you will be able to transition it. [Using the shell context menu](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0006/Using_the_shell_context_menu.htm)

EDIT:
Here is another link to a project with ready to use code (C#):

[Explorer shell context menu](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22012/Explorer-Shell-Context-Menu)

Comment: It'll take me a while to work through that link - but it looks promising.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to take a little while to digest this.  But it looks like the second link is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: Make that - I'm going to take *quite* a while to digest this. ;)

Comment: I took a look at it, too. Seems to be quite a lot of "native" code. But I think it will be indeed what you were searching for.

Comment: you may also wish to read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3551/C-does-Shell-Part-1 .  I'm working my way through that now to try to understand the code.  It looks extremely promising though.  Most likely this will be the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully I didn't violate protocol waiting over the weekend before I accepted.  I needed some time to digest what I had.  It works a treat though.  Thanks @Romano Zumbé!!